# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am trying to integrate HBase and HIVE .
i have added

```
jar guava-r09.jar
hbase-0.92.0.jar
hive-hbase-handler-0.9.0.jar
zookeeper-3.3.4.jar
```

In the /usr/lib/hive/lib folder and then restarted my cloudera .
I am using Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0 version .

But when creating external table getting following exception .

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: PBUF

quickstart.cloudera���ʼ��+��
```

I have tried adding like this also

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>
file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0-cdh5.7.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-rest-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar,
file:///usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-thrift-1.2.0-cdh5.8.0.jar
</value>
</property>
```

But then getting below exception

```
/usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase-0.92.0.jar (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

its version mismatch. you are adding both hbase 0.92.0 and hbase 1.2.0